How to make AgentForce process instruction in a predefined order?
When instructions are provided to AgentForce, they are processed in random order.
How can we make AgentForce process instruction in a predefined order?

Copy all the instruction and make one single big instructions block

Then the instructions will be processed in the correct order.
